# How to separate a list of characters following a sequence in Python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, list

I am trying to separate the following list:

**['\nYear\nMonth\nValue\n', '\n2023\nAugust\n(p) 164.06\n', '\n2023\nJuly\n(sf) (r) 148.02\n']**

such that the values will be reflected as shown in the table below:

| Year | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | August | (p) 164.06 |
| 2023 | July | sf) (r) 148.02 |

The first item of the list is separated into 3 column headers: Year, Month, Value. I used bs4 to scrape a website but the data came in a list formatted in a way which is hard to work with.

Hoping someone would be able to share the code to manipulate the said list in a dataframe version.

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solution is to use `pd.read_csv`:

```py
from io import StringIO

lst = [
    "\nYear\nMonth\nValue\n",
    "\n2023\nAugust\n(p) 164.06\n",
    "\n2023\nJuly\n(sf) (r) 148.02\n",
]


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(s.strip().replace("\n", ",") for s in lst)))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Year   Month            Value
0  2023  August       (p) 164.06
1  2023    July  (sf) (r) 148.02
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
scraped = ['\nYear\nMonth\nValue\n', 
    '\n2023\nAugust\n(p) 164.06\n', 
    '\n2023\nJuly\n(sf) (r) 148.02\n']
clean_data = [item.split('\n')[1:-1] for item in scraped]
```

or not one liner:

```
clean_data = []
for item in scraped:
    clean_data = item.split('\n')[1:-1]
```

this is the clean_data

```
clean_data = [
['Year', 'Month', 'Value'], 
['2023', 'August', '(p) 164.06'], 
['2023', 'July', '(sf) (r) 148.02']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data
['\nYear\nMonth\nValue\n', '\n2023\nAugust\n(p) 164.06\n', '\n2023\nJuly\n(sf) (r) 148.02\n']
>>> data[0].strip()
'Year\nMonth\nValue'
>>> data[0].strip().split('\n')
['Year', 'Month', 'Value']
>>> new_data = [row.strip().split('\n') for row in data]
>>> new_data
[['Year', 'Month', 'Value'], ['2023', 'August', '(p) 164.06'], ['2023', 'July', '(sf) (r) 148.02']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(new_data[1:], columns=new_data[0])
>>> df
   Year   Month            Value
0  2023  August       (p) 164.06
1  2023    July  (sf) (r) 148.02
```